# INET_ATON in where statement doctrine2 querybuilder zend2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

Question: I want to run a query with querybuilder in Doctrine2 like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `column1` = 'x' and (`column2` = INET_ATON('1.1.1.1') OR `column3` like '%bla%'...)
```

How should I do this in Doctrine2 with Zend2?

I tried this:

```
$where->add($qb->expr()->eq('column2', $qb->expr()->literal('inet_aton('1.1.1.1'))));
```

But that doen't work. Doctrine still adds quotes around the inet_aton function.

Comment: Does this help -> https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/gdCG5MoByD4

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623257/doctrine-2-dql-mysql-equivalent-to-round

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself:

A few things you should do:

First make a DQL function

```
<?php

namespace Application\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class InetAtonFunction extends \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode
{
    public $valueExpression = null;

    /**
     * parse
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->valueExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    /**
     * getSql
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'INET_ATON('. $this->valueExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')'; 
    }
}
```

After that add the function to the Doctrine ORM

```
<?php
namespace Observer;

//...

class Module implements
    AutoloaderProviderInterface,
    ConfigProviderInterface,
    ServiceProviderInterface
{
//...
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {

        $application = $e->getParam('application');
        $sm  = $application->getServiceManager();
        $em  = $application->getEventManager();

        $entityManager = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        $entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomStringFunction('inet_aton', 'Application\DQL\InetAtonFunction');       
    }
...
```

After this your good to go.
Now you can run queries with querybuilder like

```
SELECT whatever FROM someting where cloumn = inet_aton(:?)
```

I hope this helps others with special function in Doctrine and Zend Framework2

Answer (score 2):

Just an answer for update : (For new SF version)

After create the DQL function (See older post),

We want to register us customize DQL class in the Yaml (config.yml) like that :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            string_functions:
                inet_aton: home\myBundle\myFolderContaintClass\InetAton
```

That was explain [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) on the official Symfony documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be a duplicate of [Doctrine 2 DQL MySQL equivalent to ROUND()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623257/doctrine-2-dql-mysql-equivalent-to-round)

You need to implement a [custom DQL function](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html) for that.

There's some examples in [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql).

You can implement it like following:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class InetAnon extends FunctionNode
{
    private $arithmeticExpression;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {

        return 'INET_ANON(' . $sqlWalker->walkSimpleArithmeticExpression(
            $this->arithmeticExpression
        ) . ')';
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {

        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->arithmeticExpression = $parser->SimpleArithmeticExpression();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

You can then register it in the configuration while bootstrapping the ORM:

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

$config->addCustomNumericFunction('INET_ANON', 'MyApp\DQL\InetAnon');
```