# Doctrine 2 DQL MySQL equivalent to ROUND()?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I know from the documentation at:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions
that there is no ROUND function but is there an easy way to do it without writing my own DQL class function?

**Edit:**
I would not need an exact match if doing an average and returning a whole number is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement a [custom DQL function](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html) for that.

There's some examples in [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql).

You can implement it like following:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class Round extends FunctionNode
{
    private $arithmeticExpression;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {

        return 'ROUND(' . $sqlWalker->walkSimpleArithmeticExpression(
            $this->arithmeticExpression
        ) . ')';
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {

        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->arithmeticExpression = $parser->SimpleArithmeticExpression();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

You can then register it in the configuration while bootstrapping the ORM:

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

$config->addCustomNumericFunction('ROUND', 'MyApp\DQL\Round');
```

Comment: Yes this looks like the only way to do it. I appreciate the directions.

Answer (score 8):

A bit cleaner approach would be using slightly modified @Ocramius code.

Put this piece of code in: `src/YourNamespace/YourMainBundle/DoctrineFunctions/` directory as the `Round.php` filename:

```
<?php
namespace YourApp\YourMainBundle\DoctrineFunctions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class Round extends FunctionNode
{
    private $arithmeticExpression;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {

        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->arithmeticExpression = $parser->SimpleArithmeticExpression();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'ROUND(' . $sqlWalker->walkSimpleArithmeticExpression($this->arithmeticExpression) . ')';
    }
}
```

Then put this in your `app/config/config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dql:
        numeric_functions:
            round: YourApp\YourMainBundle\DoctrineFunctions\Round
```

That would allow you to use the `ROUND()` function directly in your DQL SELECT queries; no matter if done with QueryBuilder or directly via `createQuery()`

Comment: Thx a lot for the hint but the config "dql" must be under "orm" (doctrine: orm: dql: ...).

Comment: Hi! I have created the `Round.php` file, added the `dql` code in the config.yml file (under `doctrine : orm : entity_managers : default` key), and I've ran a `app/console cache:clear` command but I still can't use the `ROUND` function in my DQL. This is the error: `Error: Expected known function, got 'ROUND'`. Do I have to do anything else? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to specify rounding precision, you can use the class that is provided [here](https://github.com/mapado/MysqlDoctrineFunctions/blob/master/DQL/MysqlRound.php). If you are using symfony, install the bundle, as you'll also get extra standard mysql functions.

The code of the linked resource is also available below:

```
<?php
namespace Mapado\MysqlDoctrineFunctions\DQL;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
/**
 * MysqlRound
 *
 * @uses FunctionNode
 * @author Julien DENIAU <julien.deniau@mapado.com>
 */
class MysqlRound extends FunctionNode
{
    /**
     * simpleArithmeticExpression
     *
     * @var mixed
     * @access public
     */
    public $simpleArithmeticExpression;
    /**
     * roundPrecision
     *
     * @var mixed
     * @access public
     */
    public $roundPrecision;
    /**
     * getSql
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'ROUND(' .
                $sqlWalker->walkSimpleArithmeticExpression($this->simpleArithmeticExpression) .','.
                $sqlWalker->walkStringPrimary($this->roundPrecision) .
        ')';
    }
    /**
     * parse
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->simpleArithmeticExpression = $parser->SimpleArithmeticExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->roundPrecision = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
        if ($this->roundPrecision == null) {
            $this->roundPrecision = 0;
        }
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```