# DQL functions - division, ROUND(),

Tags: symfony

I have the following DQL query:

```
SELECT CONCAT((t.price/100), ROUND(t.value/100, 2)) FROM AcmeBundle:Transactions t
```

And it throws me errors on the first division and the round function:

```
Expected known function, got 'ROUND'
```

and

```
Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '('
```

Is there a way to solve this problem, without using native sql? Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623257/doctrine-2-dql-mysql-equivalent-to-round

Comment: Hm, and how can I register custom ROUND function in symfony 2?

Comment: See the doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Comment: You might need to look into aggregate functions in Doctrine.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 DQL MySQL equivalent to ROUND()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623257/doctrine-2-dql-mysql-equivalent-to-round)